# spring boot app actually running on port 0, instead of random

Tags: spring, spring-boot, port

my application.properties file contains

```
server.port=0
```

Which is supposed to be captured by spring boot and set it to a random port.

Instead it actually launches it on port 0, its even in the spring log as such:

```
01/Mar/2019 12:50:43,600- TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
```

Eureka sees it as an 'up' service, and provides the link to the service (`localhost:0/info`), clicking on it gives my browser '`ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`', guessing because its not a valid port..

App is running to send heartbeats to Eureka, but why is spring not setting it a random port number?

Are there any settings that can prevent the random? if so how to unset them?

**edit:** any new boot apps the server.port=0 is random, its just not working for an existing spring boot application that lots of dependencies

Comment: What is your spring boot version where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Karol Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE with Greenwich.SR1

Comment: The application starts on proper dynamic port but Eureka sees port as 0 only

Comment: @GauravVarma check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491970/eureka-not-able-to-find-port-when-running-microservices-on-random-port

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't actually start it on port 0, it starts it on a random port.
In your eureka server you will see that it is in port 0 but if you put yourself on top without clicking you will see in the browser bar that the port is different.

In the log it shows:

```
INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
```

but later changes it:

```
INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 64039 (http) with context path ''
INFO  o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration - Updating port to 64039
```

So if you have problems communicating with each other, it is because in every microservice you start with random port would have to configure in your `application.yml` a `preferIpAddress` to find it by ip and not by hostname:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:portServer/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

Comment: I have setup preferIpAddress as true, but the problem is still there

Comment: I guess you have the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency to access the url `host:port/actuator/info`,
Have you tried a firefox browser if you get the same error?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set port programmatically:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container -> {
            container.setPort(new Random().nextInt(65_535) + 1_000);
        });
    }
}
```

Also, this might help: [Eureka not able to find port when running microservices on random port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491970/eureka-not-able-to-find-port-when-running-microservices-on-random-port)

Comment: That did launch the app on a random port, although possibly too late, as eureka still is looking at port 0

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud are you using?